# Sharepoint Site Download a file Using Microsoft Graph 1.0

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

What is wrong with this:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/insuriasa.sharepoint.com:/Sites/IFS:/drive/root/children

At the end of the day I want to be able to download this:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/insuriasa.sharepoint.com:/Sites/IFS:/drive/root:/Std Forms/Discovery Invest/Servicing/change_of_contribution_form_retirement_annuity_plan.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download the file content in a web application you should do a [GET](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get) call on the item with **?select=@content.downloadUrl** parameter. In the response you will get a pre-authenticated url in the property **'@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl'** on that you can do a get call without passing any extra authentication header to download the file.

If you are using in native clients then this [Download Endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get_content) should work fine.

Comment: I am doingthis using VBA so without going ito the whole access token area which worked in onedrive...

Comment: AccessToken = GetAccessToken
    If AccessToken <> "" Then
        TmpURl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0"
        TmpURl = TmpURl & "/sites/insuriasa.sharepoint.com:/Sites/IFS:"
        TmpURl = TmpURl & "/drive/root:"
        'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/insuriasa.sharepoint.com:/Sites/IFS:/drives
        'TmpURl = TmpURl & "/sites/IFS/Share Documents"
        TmpURl = TmpURl & Replace(PrtFldrPth, "\", "/") & "/" & FleNme
        Debug.Print TmpURl

Comment: Set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        oHTTP.Open "GET", TmpURl, False
        oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & AccessToken
        oHTTP.send

Comment: First step is to obtain the valid graph token there are library available both for client side and server side. Do you have a valid token? Can you do the /me call to validate that?

Comment: I Have Valid Token and Refresh Token - Managed to get Download working by getting drive ID and then the download url from the JSON Response - Ill post the solution if anyone needs it...

Comment: Now have an issue uploading a file to a known folder - Uploading C:\InsuriaExports\171010134423.pdf TO /Client Files/Cawood IB 270469/K Clients/Kupferman TA 080952/20171011 DI RA contribution change.pdf

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": "-2130575312, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
    "message": "The URL 'Shared Documents/Client Files/Cawood IB 270469/K Clients/Kupferman TA 080952/20171011 DI RA contribution change.pdf' is invalid.  It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "e9c1e2ad-cf4b-4247-bd06-1078249fdd57",
      "date": "2017-10-12T07:04:38"
    }
  }
}

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!XXsbeoN_2EuTdADXQOnGBrehUmRr2AVInxTkFOqVq0CUIdXs9kfQTbIW9swFcBS2/items/01OT3K2V44CSBKPU2AJBAY5PY27KUUFAXR:/20171011 DI RA contribution change.pdf:/content

Comment: Why Am I Getting "is invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web"